# Lyx/Xetex/Texlive2009, error: Font \zf@basefont=Arial at 10.0pt not loadable: Metric (TFM) file or installed

Tags: xetex, lyx, fontspec

I just lost my laptop and reinstalled Ubuntu (12.04) on my new laptop (texlive 2009, as it comes pre-installed). My local TEXMF tree had luckily been backed up via Ubuntu 1. After installing I have been trying to compile some previous made lyx documents and encountered various problems. Most of them I could fix by googling and re-installing packages via the CTAN repository. And I managed to limit the amount of errors until I couldn't solve the last ones. Now when I try compile my document Lyx gives the following errors:

```
Font \zf@basefont=Arial at 10.0pt not loadable: Metric (TFM) file or installe  
Undefined control sequence.  
Font \zf@basefont=Arial at 10.0pt not loadable: Metric (TFM) file or installe  
Font \@tempfontb=Arial at 10.0pt not loadable: Metric (TFM) file or installed  
Font EU1/Arial(0)/m/n/7.5=Arial:letterspace=11.45; at 7.5pt not loadable: Met
```

When I am trying the exported (plain) latex document via the terminal and via the following command `xelatex filename.tex`, it spits out the following output:

```
This is XeTeX, Version 3.1415926-2.2-0.9995.2 (TeX Live 2009/Debian) entering extended mode (./TOR-Awene.tex LaTeX2e <2009/09/24> Babel <v3.8l> and hyphenation patterns for english, usenglishmax, dumylang, noh yphenation, loaded. (/usr/share/texmf-texlive/tex/latex/base/article.cls Document Class: article 2007/10/19 v1.4h Standard LaTeX document class (/usr/share/texmf-texlive/tex/latex/base/size10.clo)) (/usr/share/texmf-texlive/tex/latex/base/inputenc.sty (/usr/share/texmf-texlive/tex/latex/base/latin9.def)) (/home/ilja/texmf/tex/latex/briefpapier/Header-GB.tex (/usr/share/texmf-texlive/tex/latex/geometry/geometry.sty (/usr/share/texmf-texlive/tex/latex/graphics/keyval.sty) (/usr/share/texmf-texlive/tex/generic/oberdiek/ifpdf.sty) (/usr/share/texmf-texlive/tex/generic/oberdiek/ifvtex.sty) (/usr/share/texmf-texlive/tex/xelatex/xetexconfig/geometry.cfg)) (/usr/share/texmf/tex/latex/xcolor/xcolor.sty (/etc/texmf/tex/latex/config/color.cfg) (/usr/share/texmf-texlive/tex/xelatex/xetex-def/xetex.def)) (/usr/share/texmf-texlive/tex/latex/titlesec/titlesec.sty) (/usr/share/texmf-texlive/tex/latex/tools/array.sty) (/usr/share/texmf-texlive/tex/latex/graphics/graphicx.sty (/usr/share/texmf-texlive/tex/latex/graphics/graphics.sty (/usr/share/texmf-texlive/tex/latex/graphics/trig.sty) (/etc/texmf/tex/latex/config/graphics.cfg))) (/home/ilja/texmf/tex/latex/lipsum/lipsum.sty) (/usr/share/texmf-texlive/tex/latex/fancyhdr/fancyhdr.sty) (/usr/share/texmf-texlive/tex/latex/base/fontenc.sty (/usr/share/texmf-texlive/tex/latex/base/t1enc.def)) (/usr/share/texmf-texlive/tex/xelatex/fontspec/fontspec.sty (/usr/share/texmf-texlive/tex/generic/ifxetex/ifxetex.sty) (/usr/share/texmf-texlive/tex/latex/tools/calc.sty) (/usr/share/texmf-texlive/tex/latex/xkeyval/xkeyval.sty (/usr/share/texmf-texlive/tex/generic/xkeyval/xkeyval.tex)) (/usr/share/texmf-texlive/tex/latex/base/fontenc.sty (/usr/share/texmf-texlive/tex/xelatex/euenc/eu1enc.def) (/usr/share/texmf-texlive/tex/xelatex/euenc/eu1lmr.fd)) fontspec.cfg loaded. (/usr/share/texmf-texlive/tex/xelatex/fontspec/fontspec.cfg)) (/usr/share/texmf-texlive/tex/latex/setspace/setspace.sty Package: `setspace' 6.7 <2000/12/01> ) (/usr/share/texmf-texlive/tex/latex/soul/soul.sty) (/usr/share/texmf-texlive/tex/latex/tools/multicol.sty) (/usr/share/texmf-texlive/tex/latex/paralist/paralist.sty) (/usr/share/texmf-texlive/tex/latex/pbox/pbox.sty (/usr/share/texmf-texlive/tex/latex/base/ifthen.sty)) kpathsea: Running mktextfm Arial /usr/share/texmf/web2c/mktexnam: Could not map source abbreviation A for Arial. /usr/share/texmf/web2c/mktexnam: Need to update /usr/share/texmf-texlive/fonts/map/fontname/special.map? mktextfm: Running mf-nowin -progname=mf \mode:=ljfour; mag:=1; nonstopmode; input Arial This is METAFONT, Version 2.718281 (TeX Live 2009/Debian)


kpathsea: Running mktexmf Arial ! I can't find file `Arial'. <*> ...e:=ljfour; mag:=1; nonstopmode; input Arial
                                                   Please type another input file name ! Emergency stop. <*> ...e:=ljfour; mag:=1; nonstopmode; input Arial
                                                   Transcript written on mfput.log. grep: Arial.log: No such file or directory mktextfm: `mf-nowin -progname=mf \mode:=ljfour; mag:=1; nonstopmode; input Arial' failed to make Arial.tfm. kpathsea: Appending font creation commands to missfont.log.

! Font \zf@basefont=Arial at 10.0pt not loadable: Metric (TFM) file or installe d font not found. \zf@fontspec ...ntname \zf@suffix " at \f@size pt 
                                                  \unless \ifzf@icu \zf@set@... l.27 \newfontface\arial[LetterSpace=11.45]{Arial}
                                                  ? ^C! Interruption. <to be read again> 
                   \let  l.27 \newfontface\arial[LetterSpace=11.45]{Arial}
```

My self-relience on finding the solution kind of stopped here. Googling didn't helpt and the fact that latex is complaining about a standard font (Arial) kind of stumps me.

Comment: XeTeX is looking for a system font. Do you have the font Arial in your system? Can you write a text with it in some standard text processing application?

Comment: @Ulrike, you were right. The solution was embarrassingly simple: install the Arial font (I assumed a mainstream font such as Arial would be included in Ubuntu by default, should have checked) Anyway, I fixed it as per these instructions: http://embraceubuntu.com/2005/09/09/installing-microsoft-fonts/

Answer (score 1):

Ubuntu doesn't have the Arial font, only its free alternatives. Change Arial to Sans, FreeSans or another installed font.